# Sorting a table similar to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I would like to know how to sort my array alphabetically which is like

```
[
  {"people":"Julien SMITH","uid":"598"},
  {"people":"John SMITH","uid":"7232"}
]
```

I tried with

```
array_multisort($myArray['people'],SORT_ASC,$myArray['uid'])
```

But of course it doesn't work because people and uid are not really columns of the table...

I can't find something similar to my case..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `usort()` function. It will do exactly what you want.

```
$jsonObj = '[
 {"people":"Julien SMITH","uid":"598"},  
{"people":"Don SMITH","uid":"7232"},
{"people":"Allan SMITH","uid":"3232"}
]';

$arrObj = json_decode($jsonObj,true);

function build_sorter($key) {
return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
    return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
};
}

usort($arrObj, build_sorter('people'));

foreach ($arrObj as $item) {
echo $item['people'] . ', ' . $item['uid'] . "n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert your json object to array. Then you can apply sorting

```
$json_obj = '[
  {"people":"Julien SMITH","uid":"598"},  
  {"people":"John SMITH","uid":"7232"}
]';
$myArray = json_decode($json_obj,true);

array_multisort($myArray,SORT_ASC);
echo json_encode($myArray); // op: [{"people":"John SMITH","uid":"7232"},{"people":"Julien SMITH","uid":"598"}]
```

Comment: It's not really working because I need to return an array like JSON, et if I do what you say, then I return json_encode($myArray), it doesn't work...